# How to uninstall a package with dnu?

Tags: dnx, dnu

I can install packages into a dnx project with `dnu install whatever`, but I haven't been able to figure out how to *uninstall* a package.

I tried just deleting the line from the project.json file and doing a `dnu restore`, but it appears to not have done the trick. (Some code that should have started failing continued to build correctly.) I also tried `dnu commands uninstall`, but that appears to be for global commands rather than packages.

I'm using dnu version 1.0.0-rc1-16231.

Comment: Does the new 'project.lock.json' file still holds reference to the removed package? I would recommend removin all 'project.lock.json' files in solution and doing 'dnu restore' on solution level.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to your `project.json` file and remove the entry from there. Then run `dnu restore` to regenerate the `project.lock.json` file.

If you want to remove the package from disk too, delete it from `%userprofile%\.dnx\packages`

Comment: Apparently I was wrong--that does indeed appear to be sufficient.